# How can I determine linux user id from inside postgres?

Tags: postgresql

RHEL6 and PG 9.6.7

How can I determine the linux user who is connected to a PG DB?  I don't want current_user (the PG user).  Rather, I want the linux user id of the person who made the connection.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get the OS username of the client while in Postgres as this info isn't passed in with the connection. [Similar question here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194343/how-to-get-os-user-in-postgres) The client may not be Linux either. It could be a Windows or Mac or what-have-you client connecting into postgres, which is why there isn't a good answer for this question.

Comment: Put simply: you can't. Particularly if it's a remote connection, it might not even be a Linux client.